# Javascript outer scope variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I access the **itemid** variable from outside the function **after click btn_add2?**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".btn_add2", function () {
        var itemid= $(this).attr('data-asset-group-id');
        console.log('test1:' + itemid);
    });
    console.log('test2:' + itemid); // how to access to variable itemid from here?
});
```

Comment: Define it outside the click event?

Comment: @AlonEitan after click btn_add2 i want to access variable

Comment: please note that delegating an event like that will, I think, trigger the event handle on each and every click anywhere. Sur nothing will actually happen because of the ".btn_add2' but still the event will be triggered. If this .btn_add2 is not dynamically generated, it might be a good idea not to use event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

You should define item variable outside click event like as below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var item = $("#item").text()
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    alert("item in click" + item);
  });
  alert(item)
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="item">TEST</span> 
<button id="btn"> click this </button>
```